# How to remind a professor (for the third time) about providing a letter of financial support?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, funding, email, canada

I have received my admission letter for a graduate program from a Canadian university. However, the letter contains no information about funding. I have already talked to my professor about the availability of funding by this email for two times.

> Hello Professor,
>
> I am writing to follow up on the letter of financial support we had discussed a while back. I was wondering if you had a chance to write it, or if you needed more documentation from me. Please let me know if I need to do anything on my end.
>
> Best, Nikki

each time he said that he will send me a letter of financial support. So far he has not sent me said the letter. What should I write to ask him again for this letter? Could you send me a template of an email which shows my concern about visa process? any other suggestion? I am fed up with sending so many emails and I really don't know what to do...

I will miss the winter semester if he doesn't send me the letter in 2weeks.

Comment: Have you tried giving him a call? Some people are simply not very good at responding to emails.

Comment: I am an international student. He doesn't use any applications like internet free call. so I can not call him.

Comment: Why not spend a few [insert unit of your currency] and call him using a normal phone?

Comment: Did you try to ask the administration at his institute/department, instead of the professor? Also check if he has a secretary and go through this route, if he does.

Answer (score 6):

How about,

> Dear Prof,
>
> I am an international student and need to apply for a visa to come to the University. I will miss the winter semester if I don't have the letter of financial support in 2 weeks.
>
> Best regards, Nikki.

Be polite but straightforward and always explain why the deadline is real. Don't hesitate to chase people - it might be that the professor is simply too busy and he keeps forgetting things which are not urgent. Note also that his understanding of urgency can be different from yours.